# How to sum all values in each column and divide each column by the summed value

Tags: python

Basically I have a `10000x10000` matrix named `M` and there are `1`s and `0`s in every column. I'm trying to count the number of `1`s in every column and then divide every element in that column with this number.

This is what I have tried:

```
outbound_links = M[M == 1].count()

mat = [[1] * 10000] * 10000
n = 10000
#len(mat)

# for each column
for col_index in range(0, n):

    # count the number of 1s
    for row_index in range(0, n):
      
      if M[row_index][col_index] == 1:
            mat[row_index][col_index] = 1 / outbound_links[col_index]
    else:
            mat[row_index][col_index] = 0

print(mat)
```

But the code is unable to run because it seems too big a matrix. I was wondering what other alternatives I could use?

Comment: I suggest you use numpy for this. Convert your matrix to a numpy array and then use the available `sum` method

Comment: Note that `mat = [[1] * 10000] * 10000` will create a "matrix" with 10k references to the same list. You have to use `[[1] * 10000 for _ in range(10000)]`, or better use `numpy`.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that a 10000x10000 matrix of bit values can probably be stored much more efficiently than a 10000x10000 matrix of float values, so maybe you should keep them as 1/0 and store the sums separately and only divide individual lines when really needed.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, you should use numpy for this. I think this will do:

```py
import numpy as np

m = np.random.randint(0, 2, (4, 4))

# array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 0]])

m / np.sum(m, axis=0)[np.newaxis, :]

# array([[0.  , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.  ],
#        [0.  , 0.25, 0.  , 0.5 ],
#        [0.  , 0.25, 0.  , 0.5 ],
#        [1.  , 0.25, 0.5 , 0.  ]])
```

Comment: wow this is really efficient! But how do you handle the columns that add up to 0?

Comment: @JayneHow That can be easily handled with [`np.errstate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html) and [`np.nan_to_num`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html).

Answer (score 0):

None `numpy` way. Simply iterate all columns, for each find the amount of ones and then divide each cell with that count:

```py
from random import randint

n = 4
mat = [[randint(0,1) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]

print(*mat, sep='\n')

for col in range(n):
    # count the number of 1s
    ones = sum(mat[row][col] for row in range(n))

    if ones:  # Avoid dividing by zero
        for row in range(n):
            mat[row][col] /= ones

print('\n', *mat, sep='\n')
```

An example run:

```
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]


[0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.33]
[0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.33]
[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.33]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array(M)
for i in range(len(mat[0])):
    try:
        mat[:,i] = mat[i,:]/np.sum(mat[:,i])
    except:
        print("no ones in that column")
```